# Call get method inside a method of a class

Tags: java, getter

I'm just learning Java a bit. I have a simple question.
I have 2 getter methods.
Does my code have any problems if I call get method inside a non-static in a class like below?
In addition, can getter method is set static. If it does, when it does.
This code is just a sample code to post here.

```
public float testAverage(){
    float aver;
    
    aver = getTest1() + getTest2();
    
    return aver;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getter and Setters are used to encapsulate instance variables.

When you make a method static it won't have access to instance variables, but only other static methods/variables within the class. Statics are used for instance-agnostic logic. As such you can only have static getter/setter methods for only static class variables.

> I have 2 getter methods. Does my code have any problems if I call get
> method inside a non-static in a class like below

As long as `getTest1` and `getTest2` are none static then you will have access to them in other none-static methods.